# Are there markers for the start and end of a string in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Basically I'm trying to remove a value (val2 for example) from a string that looks like 'val1,val2,val3'. However the values can be arranged in any order and I want to avoid ending up with stuff like ',val1,val3', 'val1,,val3' or 'val1,val3,'. I thought about replacing 'val2' with '' and then replacing ',,', ',end' and 'start,' with ','. But I don't know what the markers for end and start of a string are.

Answer (score 0):

Storing multiple values in one single column is never a good idea. You should think about redesign your data model.

You can get what you want with regular expressions, see [MYSQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#id669724). There are two characters `^` and `$` that match beginning and end of a string.

Comment: I would but redesigning the data model is not my responsability. Besides, I'm using it to store the order in which the customers want to see the headers on their table and since it's customized for every license and every different table I don't see how else I could store them in an efficient manner. I could be wrong tho.

Comment: Storing multiple values in a single column is the opposite of *efficient manner*.